# aws s3 bucket search subfolders

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda

The article in the following link

```
https://alexwlchan.net/2017/07/listing-s3-keys/
```

helps as far as objects are in parent folder
How will it be possible to accomplish to also read objects in subfolders
I tried to use `mybucket.objects.filter(Prefix=someprefix)` but it wont look for objects in subfolders
`mybucket.objects.all()` will work(it looks into subfolders as well) but when there are millions of files in a bucket,the calling lambda function will timeout

Comment: To query some (not all) objects, you're going to have to provide a prefix e.g. /one/two/three/. If not all of the objects that you are interested in have the same prefix then you're going to have to issue multiple requests, one per prefix, and aggregate the results.

Comment: There's no such thing as "folders" in S3, just so you know. S3 Buckets have a flat hierarchy containing S3 Objects. The representation of S3 objects in "folders" in the AWS Management Console is purely for visual organization. Hence, to answer your question, you specify a Key Prefix when calling the ListObjects API. Note that results are limited to 1,000 per data page. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/v2-RESTBucketGET.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've already discovered, each instance of your Lambda function has a [finite lifetime and memory capacity](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/limits.html). Since you have millions of objects in your S3 Bucket, you'll need to delegate your work out to many instances of your Lambda function, not just a single instance.

### Solution: Data Paging

Your solution here, as noted in the article you linked to, is to use data paging. The continuation token that's provided on the first response to the [List Objects V2 API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/v2-RESTBucketGET.html) is what you need to pass into the next invocation. When there is no longer a `continuation-token` provided, you've reached the end of your search results.

According to the document linked above, the `IsTruncated` property, on the response object, will be set to `true`. However, the article you linked to isn't checking this property, and instead simply checking for a `KeyError` exception, which should be adequate. Then, in your next invocation of your Lambda function, pass in the value of `continuation-token` into the `event` object.

## Updated Python Function

Check out the copy-pasted Python function from the article you linked to, and look where the comment I inserted is. That's the point where you would want to invoke your Lambda function recursively and asynchronously.

You can use the `boto3` library to invoke your Lambda function, using the `invoke()` [method document here](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/lambda.html#Lambda.Client.invoke). Make sure that you specify the `InvocationType` = `event` parameter, as that will cause the Lambda function to execute asynchronously. Also make sure to pass the `continuation-token` into the `Payload` method parameter, as your next Lambda invocation will need to accept that as input, and pass it into the next [`list_objects_v2()` request](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.list_objects_v2).

```
def get_all_s3_keys(bucket):
    """Get a list of all keys in an S3 bucket."""
    keys = []

    kwargs = {'Bucket': bucket}
    while True:
        resp = s3.list_objects_v2(**kwargs)
        for obj in resp['Contents']:
            keys.append(obj['Key'])

        try:
            ### Invoke your Lambda function recursively here
            kwargs['ContinuationToken'] = resp['NextContinuationToken']
        except KeyError:
            print('There is no continuation token, aborting ...')
            break

    return keys
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try with this example:

```
var client = new Amazon.S3.AmazonS3Client(Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1);
ListObjectsRequest request = new ListObjectsRequest
                {
                    BucketName = bucketName,
                    Prefix = prefix
                };
// Build your call out to S3 and store the response
ListObjectsResponse response = client.ListObjects(request);
IEnumerable<S3Object> folders = response.S3Objects;
```

Enter the folder name into the prefix for search subFolders or files.